# Does joomla have search for content?

Tags: search, joomla

I am trying to find a search feature that searches all contents, including articles, links, posts, etc. in Joomla. Where is it located?

I am talking about search feature in administration page, not home page. I want to be able to figure out where the content is coming from and its location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any search capabilities directly in the administration console for Joomla.

The standard search extension you add to the actual site should give you this information though.