# joomla backend search feature that searches all contents (articles, links, posts..)

Tags: search, joomla, joomla2.5, backend, joomla-extensions

this question has been asked in 2010 ([Does joomla have search for content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353715/does-joomla-have-search-for-content)), but without success. Any update since?

> I'm trying to find a search feature that searches all contents,
>   including articles, links, posts, etc. in Joomla. Where is it located?
>
> I am talking about search feature in administration page, not home
>   page. I want to be able to figure out where the content is coming from
>   and its location.

ps: the "smart search content" plugin included in the core of joomla is very limited **in backend**: it only search in articles title, and worst, it skips some articles in front-end   yet plugin enable, indexer done, all publish inside indexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backup solution :

set a "smart search module" in the frontend (for register user so it won't bother) it will retrieve any content field from the DB

Comment: I recommend also RSFinder! (seems to onmy search within title, but save a lot of time) could be use with smart search. still waiting for the perfect extension that ll search within article contents...